# java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'

Tags: java, sql, spring, rest, derby

I'm developing and deploying a RESTful service in JBOSS EAP 6.2. For this task I'm using CXF, Spring and Embedded Derby for the data storage.
I spent a couple of hours trying to debug this error but can't achieve it. I already checked many times that the database is completely empty and there isn't any table. But I always receive the same stack trace.
I also read similar questions but that did'nt helped either.
So, here is the code:

Resource class

```
package rest_3;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@Path("/dataservice")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public class DataService {

    private ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rest_3/servicebean.xml");
    private DAO dao = (DAO) context.getBean("daoBean");

    public DataService(DAO dao) {

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/location/{id}")
    public Location getLocation(@PathParam("id") int id) throws SQLException {
        Location loc = dao.getLocation(id);
        if (loc == null) {
            ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST);
            builder.type("application/xml");
            builder.entity("<error>Location Not Found</error>");
            throw new WebApplicationException(builder.build());
        } 
        return loc;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/location")
    public Response addLocation(Location loc) throws SQLException {
        if(loc == null)
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        dao.addLocation(loc);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/location/{id}")
    public Response deleteLocation(@PathParam("id") int id) throws SQLException {
        Location loc = dao.getLocation(id);
        if(loc == null) 
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        dao.deleteLocation(id);
        return Response.ok().build();

    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/location")
    public Response updateLocation(Location loc) throws SQLException {
        if(dao.getLocation(loc.getId()) == null)
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        dao.updateLocation(loc);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/location")
    public void dropTable() throws SQLException {
        dao.dropTable();
    }


}
```

DAO Class

```
package rest_3;


import java.sql.*;

import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource;

public class DAO {

    private static Connection conn;
    private static Statement statement;
    private static PreparedStatement prep;

    public DAO() throws SQLException {
        this.load();
    }

    public void load() throws SQLException {

        EmbeddedDataSource ds = new EmbeddedDataSource(); 
        ds.setDatabaseName("derbyDB");
        ds.setCreateDatabase("create");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute("create table location(id int, country varchar(40))");
        statement.execute("insert into location values(1, 'MEXICO')");
        statement.execute("insert into location values(2, 'SPAIN')");
        statement.execute("insert into location values(3, 'UK')");
        statement.execute("insert into location values(4, 'ITALY')");
        statement.execute("insert into location values(5, 'JAPAN')");

    }


    public Location getLocation(int id) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select from location where id = "  + id);
        rs.next();
        return new Location(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("country"));
    }

    public void addLocation(Location loc) throws SQLException{
        int id = loc.getId();
        String country = loc.getCountry();
        prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into location values(?,?)");
        prep.setInt(1, id);
        prep.setString(2, country);
        prep.execute();
    }

    public void deleteLocation(int id) throws SQLException{
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("delete from location where id = " + id);

    }

    public void updateLocation(Location loc) throws SQLException {
        int id = loc.getId();
        String country = loc.getCountry();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute("update location set country = " + country + " where id = " + id);
    }

    public void dropTable() throws SQLException {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute("drop table location");
    }

}
```

Service and DAO beans.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataService" class="rest_3.DataService">
    <constructor-arg ref ="daoBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="daoBean" class="rest_3.DAO">
</bean>

</beans>
```

Service bean config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
  xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml" />
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
 <jaxrs:server id="DataService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:features>
     <cxf:logging/>
</jaxrs:features>
<jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="dataService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/beans.xml
        classpath:rest_3/servicebean.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Stack trace:

```
16:28:05,892 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rest_3]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataService' while setting bean property 'serviceBeans' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataService' defined in class path resource [rest_3/servicebean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoBean' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoBean' defined in class path resource [rest_3/servicebean.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [rest_3.DAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729) [spring-context-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381) [spring-context-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255) [spring-web-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199) [spring-web-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45) [spring-web-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataService' defined in class path resource [rest_3/servicebean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoBean' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoBean' defined in class path resource [rest_3/servicebean.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [rest_3.DAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:495) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:162) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoBean' defined in class path resource [rest_3/servicebean.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [rest_3.DAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [rest_3.DAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at rest_3.DAO.load(DAO.java:25) [classes:]
    at rest_3.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:15) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 59 more
Caused by: ERROR X0Y32: Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.duplicateDescriptorException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.addDescriptor(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.CreateTableConstantAction.executeConstantAction(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.MiscResultSet.open(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) [derby-10.12.1.1.jar:]
    ... 69 more

16:28:05,938 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /rest_3 start, will stop it
16:28:05,938 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rest_3]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
16:28:05,938 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./rest_3: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./rest_3: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Falló iniciar contexto
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Falló iniciar contexto
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Do you get this error on the first time you invoke your REST service or only on the next calls?

Comment: It displays every moment I start JBoss with the service deployed.

Comment: What makes you think the table doesn't exist? The exception very clearly states that: "Table/View 'LOCATION' already exists in Schema 'APP'."  You only need to create the table once; after that, the table remains in existence until you "DROP TABLE" or destroy the entire database.

Comment: I already tried "drop table location" and it also showed an error saying It can't be deleted because it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted this line and now it works fine.

```
statement.execute("create table location(id int, country varchar(40))");
```

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc for `setCreateDatabase()` (emphasis mine):

> Parameters:
>   create - if set to the string "create", this data source will try to create a new database of databaseName, ***or boot the database if one by that name already exists***.

So, the first time you run your code the database gets created and the table gets created. The second time the database is NOT recreated, and the `create table` fails because it already exists.

It is really bad code smell to create a database and table in the constructor of your DAO.  If you *really* must do this, make sure to drop the database prior to attempting to create it.  If that doesn't work with your design, then you have just discovered why creating the database in the constructor is a bad idea.

Comment: Is there any chance of a bug in derby? I mean, I created a new db and still did'nt work. That can't be, maybe the table exists in the first db, but I created other one and I get the same error. Also, I can't find where this embedded derby saves the db, so I could'nt delete it yet. In Derby, there's no drop database command, so it must be deleted from the OS file system.

Comment: I think the core of your problem is that you aren't understanding where Derby is saving your database. It will be saved in a folder with the same name as your database name, typically in the "current working directory" when your application is run, which means it is probably inside the JBoss folder tree somewhere. Try searching your hard disk for a folder named "derbyDB".

Comment: Thanks. I found the database files. They were under C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.2-blank\bin. I think If I delete them all, I could create a new database with table location without errors. But haven't tried yet.

Comment: None of that changes the fact that this is a brittle design, and putting major external side effects in a constructor is really bad code smell.  I'd recommend rethinking this if at all possible.